# Como inserir um link para outra pg em cada imagem desse menu

Tags: javascript, html5, css-hover

Boa noite pessoal sou novo no assunto e achei um menu bem interessante no codepen - https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/wWVZAW estou mandando o link do projeto original porque mexi tanto no que eu baixei que nao consigo mais me achar... o negocio deve ser facil pra vcs, ocorre que ao tentar inserir um link em cada imagem do menu, após abrir o menu o link ate e reconhecido - http://prntscr.com/g6ky0h mais quando clico nele ao invés de abrir o site ele fecha o menu. Alguem pode me dar um help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".main.button").on('click',function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 if($this.text() === 'Menu') {
  $(".menu").removeClass('closed');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $this.text("Fechar");
  }, 100);
 }
 if($this.text() === 'Fechar'){
  $(".menu").addClass('closed');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $this.text("Menu");
  }, 100);
 }
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:400,500";
html {
  background: #f8f7f2;
}

.menu, .button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.125s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: -webkit-transform 1.125s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: transform 1.125s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: transform 1.125s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92), -webkit-transform 1.125s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
          transform-origin: top left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 33%;
  font: 25px/100px Alegreya Sans, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: transform 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  transition: transform 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92), -webkit-transform 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.39, 1.52, 0.46, 0.92);
  will-change: transform;
}
.button.closed {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.main {
  color: #030f01;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  line-height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(3, 15, 1, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.75s, color 0.75s;
  transition: border-color 0.75s, color 0.75s;
  will-change: color, border-color, background;
}
.closed .main {
  color: #f8f7f2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(3, 15, 1, 0);
}

.home {
  background-color: #1ba5cd;
  top: 0%;
  left: 225%;
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/cdpn/home.svg);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.525s;
          transition-duration: 0.525s;
}
.closed .home {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-225%, -10%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
          transform: translate3d(-225%, -10%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
}

.music {
  background-color: #1ab254;
  top: 86.10368%;
  left: 207.873%;
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/cdpn/music.svg);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.675s;
          transition-duration: 0.675s;
}
.closed .music {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-198.36244%, -89.19384%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
          transform: translate3d(-198.36244%, -89.19384%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
}

.messages {
  background-color: #fec72e;
  top: 159.09908%;
  left: 159.09908%;
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/cdpn/messages.svg);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.825s;
          transition-duration: 0.825s;
}
.closed .messages {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-153.22122%, -151.00892%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
          transform: translate3d(-153.22122%, -151.00892%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
}

.places {
  background-color: #fa7d39;
  top: 207.873%;
  left: 86.10368%;
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/cdpn/places.svg);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.975s;
          transition-duration: 0.975s;
}
.closed .places {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.98154%, -199.78284%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
          transform: translate3d(-91.98154%, -199.78284%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
}

.bookmark {
  background-color: #ee5656;
  top: 225%;
  left: 0%;
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/cdpn/bookmark.svg);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1.125s;
          transition-duration: 1.125s;
}
.closed .bookmark {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-9.51056%, -228.09016%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
          transform: translate3d(-9.51056%, -228.09016%, 0) rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu closed'>
  <a class='messages button' href='google.com'>Google</a>
  <a class='music button' href='fb.com'>Facebook</a>
  <a class='home button' href='uol.com'>Uol</a>
  <a class='places button' href='g1.com'>G1</a>
  <a class='bookmark button' href='youtube.com'>Youtube</a>
  <div class='main button'>Menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado WMSouza, não iria conseguir mesmo o meu HTML ate que nao estava tão errado mais vi as alterações no index.js e realmente funcionou. Grato pelo colaboração.